# VCLibs AppX package causing an error when sideloaded as a package dependecy

Tags: uwp, appx, sideloading, dism

I'm trying to side-load an appxbundle (Lenovo Vantage) which fails. The appxbundle has multiple dependencies of which one is causing an issue.

The command used to side-load is:

```
dism.exe /Online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackagePath:"Lenovo Vantage\33880b99e2af47f89fd9c3419314052e.appxbundle" /LicensePath:"Lenovo Vantage\33880b99e2af47f89fd9c3419314052e_License1.xml" /DependencyPackagePath:"Lenovo Vantage\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.7_1.7.27413.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe.appx" /DependencyPackagePath:"Lenovo Vantage\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7_1.7.25531.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe.appx" /DependencyPackagePath:"Lenovo Vantage\Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement_10.0.19011.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe.appx" /DependencyPackagePath:"Lenovo Vantage\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe.appx"
```

The returned error message is

```
2019-08-31 15:37:27, Error   DISM   DISM Appx Provider: PID=9864 TID=7564 Failed to get installed location of package 'Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe' because it's not staged - CPackageAdapter::DetermineInstalledLocationOnline(hr:0x80004005)
2019-08-31 15:37:27, Error   DISM   DISM Appx Provider: PID=9864 TID=7564 Failed to determine installed location for package 'E046963F.LenovoCompanion_4.27.32.0_neutral_~_k1h2ywk1493x8' and its dependencies - CPackageAdapter::RegisterStagedPackageOnline(hr:0x80004005)
```

Now I contacted Lenovo about it already, but they keep saying that the VCLibs appx package can't be installed as *Local System*. They're not referencing any official documentation, and my experience in system administration makes me quite suspicious about that statement.